# Country state city drop-down select options are storing in database base on their id number in Laravel 9

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, database, dropdown

I'm trying to create a user registration form and in which i add a Country, State, City, drop-down list in using laravel 9. when i select a country, state, city and submit the form. Their id number stored in database instead of thir name.  [image: This happen when i select country, state, city from down-down]

in this image the numbers are country state city which i select from drop down.
I used Route, Controller, JQuery and Ajax in Laravel 9.

Route:

```
Route::get('/register', [CountryStateCityController::class, 'getcountry']);
Route::POST('/getstate ', [CountryStateCityController::class, 'getstate']);
Route::POST('/getcity ', [CountryStateCityController::class, 'getcity']);
```

Controller:

```
class CountryStateCityController extends Controller
{
    public function getcountry() {
        $country = DB::table('countries')->get();
        $data = compact('country');
        return view('RegistrationForm')->with($data);
    }

    public function getstate(Request $request) {
        $state = State::where('country_id', '=', $request->country_id)->orderBY('state_name', 'asc')->get();
        $data = compact('state');
        return response()->json($data);
    }

    public function getcity(Request $request) {
        $city = City::where('state_id', '=', $request->state_id)->orderBY('city_name', 'asc')->get();
        $data = compact('city');
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

JQuery and Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#country').change(function () {
    var cid = this.value;   //let cid = $(this).val(); we cal also write this.
    $.ajax({
      url: "getstate",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
      data: {
        country_id: cid,
      },
      success: function(result) {
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select State</option>');
        $.each(result.state, function(key, value) {
          $('#state').append('<option value="' +value.state_id+ '">' +value.state_name+ '</option>');
        });
      },
      errror: function(xhr) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
  });

  $('#state').change(function () {
    var sid = this.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: "getcity",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
      data: {
        state_id: sid,
      },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select City</option>');
        $.each(result.city, function(key, value) {
          $('#city').append('<option value="' +value.city_id+ '">' +value.city_name+ '</option>')
        });
      },
      errror: function(xhr) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Please tell me how can i store their name in database instead of their id number.
And a little question. In ajax when we write code to store value when country change and and make an alert to show if its working or not. then the output will be the id number of country.

```
$('#country').change(function () {
    var cid = this.value;
    alert(cid);
```

Like this. So i want to ask; how can we store the name of the country instead of their number/value.

Comment: *"Please tell me how can i store their name in database instead of their id number."* - You don't. You store the `id` in the database, so you can link the tables without repeating data. When you display the data on the front end, you would do something like `$row->country->name`, `$row->state->name`, `$row->city->name`, etc. Read the basics on Laravel's Models and Relationships. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships.

Comment: Alternatively, if you need to access the `id` from database, `$row->country_id`, or `$row->country->id` (same with `state->id` and `state_id`, `city_id` and `city->id`). You have proper data normalization right now, please don't change this to use names in those columns; that makes your `countries`, `states` and `cities` tables completely irrelevant, and breaks data normalization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two ways to solve this question:

1. By passing option selected text from your dropdown instead it's value.
   Something like:

```
<select id="country_id">
    <option> Select your country </option>
    <option value = "1"> Afghanistan </option>
    <option value = "2"> Albania</option>
    <option value = "3"> Algeria</option>
</select>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#country_id').change(function() {
    let selection = $('#country option:selected'); // here we capture option selected
    $("#registrationForm")
    .append(
    $('<input>', {type: 'hidden', id: 'selected_country', name: 'country', value: selection.text()}); 
    // here we are adding a hidden field to the registration form (with id:"registrationForm")
    // with name country and value received from option selected by the user. 
  });
});
</script>
```

Later in your controller you will have a new variable named *country* that will contains a string with the name of the country selected by the user, and that can be used as `$country = $request->get('country);`

2. By managing in your controller to find state and country by id

Using this alternative you don't change anything in your Ajax. You have to find by id the name of state and country, and the insert it in your data array before save it to DB.

Comment: Thanks For your reply. Can you please specify how can i save name their name in the database what should i write in this CountryStateCityController.......  ( $users->country = $request['country'];
        $users->state = $request['state'];
        $users->city = $request['city']; ) ..... this is how i save them. this code is in another controller. Please tell me how I can store the country state city name in this when I select option. what will be the code?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a way to send the string to your processing controller. If something is not clear, just let me know and show me your processing function in order to expand my compression of your situation. Regards